# IdFTP.Connect via proxy server

Tags: delphi, ftp, delphi-xe, indy

Our Delphi application is trying to connect to our website via IdFTP on a client machine using a proxy server, and I always get a 'read timed out' message. I don't know how to fix it.

My code:

```
IdFTP1.Host        :=Website_address;
IdFTP1.Username    :=Website_user;
IdFTP1.Password    :=Website_password;
IdFTP1.TransferType:=ftBinary;

IdFTP1.ProxySettings.ProxyType:=fpcmNone; 
IdFTP1.ProxySettings.Host     :=Proxy_server;
IdFTP1.ProxySettings.Port     :=Proxy_port;
IdFTP1.ProxySettings.Username :=Proxy_username;
IdFTP1.ProxySettings.Password :=Proxy_password; 

IdFTP1.Connect;
```

...which returns a 'read timed out' exception.

Having looked on the web for possible solutions, I have tried various combinations of the following with no joy (although there might be a combination that might work, I just don't really know what I'm doing):

```
IdFTP1.IOHandler                :=TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create
                                                    (IdFTP1);
IdFTP1.UseTLS                   :=utUseExplicitTLS;
IdFTP1.NATKeepAlive.UseKeepAlive:=True;
IdFTP1.NATKeepAlive.IdleTimeMS  :=100000;
IdFTP1.DataPortProtection       :=ftpdpsPrivate;
```

The frustrating thing is I can't test it on my machine, I have to compile a new version of the application, copy it to their machine, and then see if it works.

There is nothing complex about the installation on the client side as far as I can tell. They have given me the proxy host address, and the proxy username and password are blank.

Other bits of the application connect to the same website via HTTP and the proxy server, and this works perfectly. So my logic is that it can't be firewalls or anything like that.

```
IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects                :=True;
IdHTTP1.ProxyParams.BasicAuthentication:=True;                                                                                             
IdHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyServer        :=Proxy_server;  
IdHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyPort          :=Proxy_port;                
IdHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyUsername      :=Proxy_username; 
IdHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyPassword      :=Proxy_password;
```

I am using Delphi XE8.

They have created a virtual server for our testing, it runs Windows 7 64 bit.

**Update**

Remy, is this the right idea? One problem I am having is the TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy component, what must be in the uses clause for this? Delphi is not recognizing it.

```
var

TempIO    : TIdIOHandlerStack;
TempProxy : TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy;
```

......

```
TempIO                 :=TIdIOHandlerStack.Create;
TempProxy              :=TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy.Create;
TempProxy.Host         :=Proxy_host;
TempIO.TransparentProxy:=TempProxy;
IdFTP1.IOHandler       :=TempIO;

IdFTP1.Connect;
```

**Update 2**

A point of clarity: the HTTP request that is successfully reaching the web server through the proxy server goes to a different web address than the FTP request. In other words, they both go through the same proxy server, but the destination addresses are different. Just in case this is of use.

I have now tried using Fiddler to find the problem, not sure if this is a great idea? My understanding is is that Fiddler acts as a proxy server, so I thought I would see if I encountered the same problem. Sure enough, can't connect.

To be clear about my steps:

Run Fiddler, and check the box that says 'Capture FTP requests'.

Update my IdHTTP component:

```
IdHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyServer:='127.0.0.1';
IdHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyPort  :=Fiddler port;
```

Update my IdFTP component:

```
IdFTP1.ProxySettings.Host:='127.0.0.1';
IdFTP1.ProxySettings.Port:=Fiddler port;
```

So now I have removed the client setup completely, I am mirroring the problem from my local machine using Fiddler as far as I can tell. If I don't use Fiddler, everything works great. If I use Fiddler as described above, then the HTTP request works correctly, but the FTP request can't connect.

Any ideas as to what I can do to try and solve this? I'm sure it is something really stupid that I'm doing wrong.

Comment: After much trial and error, it turns out the problem was on the client side. The code under the first 'Update' header above is correct and works well when trying to connect via FTP through an HTTP proxy. Ignore the text under 'Update 2'. Trying to test using Fiddler didn't work at all, I ended up using CCProxy which was very helpful. Thanks again @Remy Lebeau for the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> IdFTP1.ProxySettings.ProxyType:=fpcmNone
> ```

This tells `TIdFTP` **not** to communicate with an FTP-aware proxy.  If you want to use the `TIdFTP.ProxySettings` properties, you need to set the `ProxyType` so `TIdFTP.Connect()` will connect to the `ProxySettings.Host` and `TIdFTP.Login()` will know what kind of commands it needs to send to login to the proxy and request a connection to the next host.

Note that `TIdFTP.ProxySettings` only works with FTP proxies.  If you need to connect to a different type of proxy, before you call `TIdFTP.Connect()` you will have to assign a `TIdIOHandler`-derived component to the `TIdFTP.IOHandler` property, and then assign a `TIdCustomTransparentProxy`-derived component to the `TIdIOHandler.TransparentProxy` property.  To connect to an HTTP proxy (which it sounds like you need, since that is what `TIdHTTP.ProxyParams` works with), use `TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy`.  To connect to a SOCKS proxy, use `TIdSocksInfo`.

Comment: Thanks @Remy Lebeau. I'm not too sure how to get this working correctly, could you have a look at my updated code above and let me know if this is the right idea, and also where I am going wrong?

Comment: Yes, that is the basic idea. The `TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy` component is in the `IdConnectThroughHttpProxy` unit. Don't forget to set its `Enabled` property to true. Also, if you want to use encrypting with FTP, you need to use an SSLIOHandler, like `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`.

Comment: Thanks again @Remy Lebeau. Still battling with this, I've tried the options suggested, all without success thus far. Could you have a look at Update 2, I have tried to solve this using a different angle, maybe you have some ideas?